# iOS UIView size

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, autolayout

I have a Controller with 4`UILabels` that are constant height throught all the iPhones, below the last`UILabel` there is a`UIView` with a page controller(with a`TableView` inside that page controller).

What I want is that the`UIView` take all the height that he cant :

example:   Screen of 600 height

4`UILABELS` = 200 height
TableView = it should get 400 height

Screen of 800 height

4`UILABELS` = 200 height
TableView = it should get 600 height

I need 1 constraint more to set the height of the view,What I have defined is :

1. EqualWidth constraints to superView
2. LeadingSpace to SuperView
3. Top Space to super VIew

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: You just need Y position, so you can pin your tableview to the bottom and it should be fine.

Comment: the problem is that i dont know what constraint get the height on that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following constraints should align everything for you so that the UILabels stack vertically, each have height 50, and stretch to the edges. The UIView will take up the remaining space regardless of the screen size.

**All UILabels**

Pin leading edge to superview

Pin trailing edge to superview

Add height constraint set to 50.0

**UILabel 1:**

Pin top edge to superview top

**UILabel 2:**

Pin top edge to UILabel 1 bottom

**UILabel 3:**

Pin top edge to UILabel 2 bottom

**UILabel 4:**

Pin top edge to UILabel 3 bottom

**UIView**

Pin leading edge to superview

Pin trailing edge to superview

Pin top edge to UILabel 4 bottom

Pin bottom edge to superview

**UITableView**

Pin leading, trailing, top and bottom to its container view so it fills the area.

Comment: The problem is that when the tableView get the data it autoresize automatically , resizing my view(even when tableview got no autolayout

Comment: Is the view holding the page view controller moving up over the UILabels? What exactly are you seeing? You will need to make sure that the table view is set to scroll. Also make sure that the page view is pinned to the edges.

Comment: It is explained on a new question since it is different problem there ->
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30641565/ios-pageview-controller-with-uitableview-resize-error

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are creating this UIViewController in a Storyboard.

You should be able to put all the labels in a container view which you give the constant height of 200 points, as you specified. Make a vertical constraint from "Top layout Guide" to said container view, maybe with the value 0. Drag an UITableView and place it below the container view. Dont give it any constraint regarding height. Make a vertical spacing between the (bottom of) container view and the (top of the) UITableView with value 0 and a vertical spacing between the (bottom of the) UITableView and the Bottom Layout Guide with value 0.

**So it will be** (V:0 means vertical spacing, constant 0):

**Top Layout Guide**
V:0
**Container View** - Height: 200
V:0
**TableView** (dynamic height)
V:0
**Bottom Layout Guide**

This should work.

(And then of course you need to create constraints regarding width and also internal constraints for each UILabel inside the container view. Let me know if you need help with that.)