# iOS - PageView controller with UITableView resize error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uipageviewcontroller

I have a controller with two`UIViews` the first one have 200 of height(constant across all iPhones) and the second one`UIViews` contain a`PageViewController` and should get the rest of the height and it does.

The problems come when the`UITableView` get the data, It resize the`UIView`, with the resize, the`UIView` now have more height than it should have ( because tableView resized it) and I am not able to scroll to the last object.

Example: Height screen = 600

First  `UIView = 200;`

Second `UIView = 400;`

Now the UITableView get the data and loads it and resize

First `UIView = 200;`

Second `UIView = 600;`

but the screen have only 600.

I tryed lots of options, try to resize the table with the original width and height of the second UIview before resize on `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
[super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

float a = self.tabla.frame.size.height;
float a2 = self.tabla.superview.frame.size.height;
//self.tabla.superview.autoresizesSubviews = false;
//self.tabla.frame = CGRectMake(self.tabla.frame.origin.x,self.tabla.frame.origin.y,self.tablaSizeWidth,self.tablaSizeHeight);
}
```

I also tryed to desactivate the AutoLayout of the`TableView` and it worked! but if I desactivate it, it desactivate for all the whole storyboard and my second UIView cant get the rest of the height (Seriously apple?!)

Constraints of UIView containing the page controller

[image: Constraints]

View of all the constraints and the layout

Note: Main view background is setted to green and PageAdapter background is setted to black.

[image]

How I can make it?

Comment: Make sure scrolling is enabled on the table view. You should not need any of the layoutSubviews code, so I would take that out. Are there any constraint error messages in the console? Also make sure the view is pinned to the bottom layout guide or superview. It should not grow below the screen if the constraint is set or it should print an error saying it had to break that constraint for some reason.

Comment: I commented the two lines you mentioned and still nothing, and no constraints broken in console, added to the question an image with the constraints that I have defined, scroll is enable since I can scroll normally ( but I cant scroll to the last item)

Comment: You should not need to use `viewDidLayoutSubviews` at all. I would remove all that. Mixing constraints with manual frame changes is not a good idea. Really need to see you view hierarchy and all the constraints.